# UIKit with 3D Viewer iOS

Tags: ios, cocos3d

I would like to import a 3D model into an iOS application for a single UIViewController.  The view will need to be rotated and zoomed. I am currently using storyboards and ARC.  I've looked the available libraries, but there seems to be a lot of scattered documentation on doing it.  Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not an easy way to do this on iOS.  Your best bet is likely to be looking into GLKit, but that still means either writing a lot of your own code to read and display the model, or finding third party code somewhere.

On Mac OS X, there is Scene Kit, but I have heard no mention of it coming to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you can load and show your 3D model in COCOS3D, you can create a Cocos3D EAGLView and add it as a subview on any view